# MySQL: Error Code: 1064. when create procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I can not find how to fix my problem,
Here is my code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE procedure SP_INS_fbUSER
    (v_email varchar(50), v_password varchar(20), v_first_name Nvarchar(20),
    v_last_name Nvarchar(20), v_full_name Nvarchar(50), v_profile_pic_arr text)
BEGIN 
    IF(exists(SELECT * FROM USER WHERE email = v_email)) then
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO USER 
            (email,password,first_name,last_name,full_name,active,profile_pic_arr) 
            VALUES 
            (v_email,v_password,v_first_name,v_last_name,v_full_name,TRUE,v_profile_pic_arr);
    END IF;
end;
DELIMITER ;
```

And here is the error message:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10

what problem in line 10 and how to fix it?

I have try this code :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE procedure SP_INS_fbUSER
    (v_email varchar(50), v_password varchar(20), v_first_name Nvarchar(20),
    v_last_name Nvarchar(20), v_full_name Nvarchar(50), v_profile_pic_arr text)
BEGIN 
    IF(exists(SELECT * FROM USER WHERE email = v_email)) then
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO USER 
            (email,password,first_name,last_name,full_name,active,profile_pic_arr) 
            VALUES 
            (v_email,v_password,v_first_name,v_last_name,v_full_name,TRUE,v_profile_pic_arr);
        END
--------^
    END IF;
end;
DELIMITER ;
```

But is still show the same error.
Then I try this code:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE procedure SP_INS_fbUSER
    (v_email varchar(50), v_password varchar(20), v_first_name Nvarchar(20),
    v_last_name Nvarchar(20), v_full_name Nvarchar(50), v_profile_pic_arr text)
BEGIN 
    IF(exists(SELECT * FROM `USER` WHERE `email` = v_email)) then
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO `USER` 
            (`email`,`password`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`full_name`,`active`,`profile_pic_arr`) 
            VALUES 
            (v_email,v_password,v_first_name,v_last_name,v_full_name,TRUE,v_profile_pic_arr);
        END
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

And it show:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF;
>   END' at line 12

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Are you using phpmyadmin?

Comment: I'm using mysql workbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE procedure SP_INS_fbUSER
    (v_email varchar(50), v_password varchar(20), v_first_name Nvarchar(20),
    v_last_name Nvarchar(20), v_full_name Nvarchar(50), v_profile_pic_arr text)
BEGIN 
    IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `USER` WHERE `email` = v_email)) THEN
       INSERT INTO `USER` 
            (`email`,`password`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`full_name`,`active`,`profile_pic_arr`) 
          VALUES 
            (v_email,v_password,v_first_name,v_last_name,v_full_name,TRUE,v_profile_pic_arr);
    END IF;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: this code show me this  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF;
 END' at line 12

Comment: @ImP try my new code and in another hand replace those `//` by `$$`

Answer (score 0):

You have no `END` for your `BEGIN`:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE procedure SP_INS_fbUSER
    (v_email varchar(50), v_password varchar(20), v_first_name Nvarchar(20),
    v_last_name Nvarchar(20), v_full_name Nvarchar(50), v_profile_pic_arr text)
BEGIN 
    IF(exists(SELECT * FROM USER WHERE email = v_email)) then
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO USER 
            (email,password,first_name,last_name,full_name,active,profile_pic_arr) 
            VALUES 
            (v_email,v_password,v_first_name,v_last_name,v_full_name,TRUE,v_profile_pic_arr);
        END
--------^
    END IF;
end//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: also,  the  create procedure statement needs to be terminated with a '//' terminator, not a semicolon. That is, the last line should be **`end//`**  rather than **`end;`**.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have try to run your code, but it still show the same error message. Please help me

Comment: Do you have any more solution, @Gordon Linoff ?